# How do I avoid a warning when I have a function that can take both mutable and immutable char*

Tags: c, types

I have a C function that accepts a `char*` as an argument and in some cases I pass a `const char*` to the function. Internally, the function copies the string before it uses it, so it can accept either a mutable string or an immutable one.

Unfortunately, this generates a warning because in some cases I am passing a const into the function. Currently, I avoid this warning by casting the input to a plain `char*`. Is that the right practice?

Comment: If you don't mutate it, why not just accept a `const char*` as parameter?

Comment: @UnholySheep Because sometimes I pass a plain char* to the function that is not const.

Comment: Is it a function that you cannot alter?

Comment: @TylerDurden It's OK to pass a `char *` to a function that accepts `const char *`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a function can accept both mutable and immutable strings, because it never actually modifies the string, it should be declared to accept `const char *`. This shouldn't cause any warnings, and there's no need to cast the argument.

Declaring a parameter as a pointer to const expresses a promise not to modify the data. You'll get errors in the function definition if it actually does try to assign through the pointer, or pass it to a function that doesn't declare that parameter `const`. But the caller is not constrained in the constness of the argument -- there's no problem passing mutable data to a function that doesn't actually mutate it.

As an example, see the declaration of `strcpy()`:

```
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

The `source` parameter is declared `const char *`, but you can copy a mutable string. But you can't pass an immutable string as the `destination` argument, of course (you would have to cast it to a non-const pointer to get the compiler to accept it, but you'll cause undefined behavior if you actually pass an immutable string).

Comment: Did you mean to say: "but you can copy an immutable string" at the end?

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote. Even though it's declared `const char *`, you can copy a `char *`.